# change base url email notifications in Wordpress/woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, email, templates, woocommerce

I am loading a woocommerce shop (https://domain.webshop.com) via an iframe in a website (https://www.domain.com). When a user registers the info is stored on the shop's domain and an email is sent out to the new regitered user with the following link: http://domain.webshop.com/myaccount. I would like to change the link in this email to https://www.domain.com/myaccount, a page which contains an iframe with the http://domain.webshop.com/myaccount page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to [overwrite](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) the WooCommerce New Account template. `templates/emails/customer-new-account.php`

You have to replace the line number 33 with the given code

```
<p>
    <?php
        printf(__('You can access your account area to view your orders and change your password here: %s.', 'woocommerce'), make_clickable('https://mydomain.nl/mijn-account/'));
    ?>
</p>
```

Just replace the Multi-line comment with your https://www.domain.com/myaccount url.

Comment: Hi Raunak, thnx.. The file looks as follows: <?php

 <p>
    <?php
        printf(__('You can access your account area to view your orders and change your password here: %s.', 'woocommerce'), make_clickable(esc_url('https://www.mydomain.nl/mijn-account/')));
    ?>
</p>
However When placing an order and registering for an account I get an internal server error.. Any ideas?

Comment: @Michel: I have updated my answer with the said url now try with this.